# provider undefined error In auto updater for electron

Tags: node.js, github, electron, vercel

im using Vercel for my electron app for auto updates I put in my Vercel app url

```
const { app, autoUpdater } = require('electron')

const server = "something-app-2u2b3jsa.johndoe.vercel.app"

const url = `${server}/update/${process.platform}/${app.getVersion()}`

autoUpdater.setFeedURL({ url })
```

but when I package it and try to run it I now get a error saying

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Unsupported provider: undefined
at Object.newError 
(/Users/raymd/Desktop/kshot.app/Contents/Resources/
```